# XPages Validation with CSJS function call from submit button

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a form that has a javascript validation function built from its previous functioning web site (i.e. old domino form).  I am in the process of converting that website to xpages.  Is it possible to tie that function as a CSJS to the save and close button like it was in the past application?

I only ask as there are lots of conditional validation requirements that would all need to be recreated that are existing in this function. .  Also the form has tab pannels, and partial refresh conditions that I would have to code around to avoid refreshes calling validation, etc.

I have a feeling I will have problems with some of the calls, example:

```
document=document1;
form1 = document.forms[0] ;
val_AlphaSuffix = form1.Suffix.value ;
var msg="";
form = document.forms[0] ;
val_Eff_Date = form.Eff_Date.value ;
if (val_Eff_Date== "") { 
    msg=msg+"Effective Date is missing.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a better way of passing the document instead of each item, I would love to see that, but if not I think this answer by Tim T.  probably is the best answer I can see:

Expression Language (e.g. #{id:Hours20}) can only be interpreted within the context of a component attribute, such as the onChange event code for a field. Once you move the code into a separate library, the code is no longer an attribute of a component, it's code that can be referenced in component attributes.

As with any other good function, design all client-side JavaScript functions to accept anything that might be context-sensitive as a parameter. For example:

```
function updateHours(inputId, outputId) {
    var hours20 = XSP.getElementById(inputId).value; 
    XSP.getElementById(outputId).value = hours20; 
}
```

Then your onChange event can reference this function, but pass in only the context-sensitive information:

```
updateHours("#{id:Hours20}", "#{id:Hours10}");
```

This way you're keeping reusable business logic in script libraries, which is always a good thing, but nothing in those libraries is assuming anything about page structure or server-side variables.
shareeditflag

answered Jan 16 '14 at 0:17
Tim Tripcony
7,73611532

Answer (score 0):

There are a few moving parts you want to look at...

If you want to perform an entire client side validation, don't tie it to a button, but use the form event `onSubmit="validate(this)"`. This will call your function with the form as parameter and you don't need to worry if you got the right form. You could use class parameters on your fields to specify generic validation requirements e.g. `class="mandatory max_50"` etc.

However be aware: client side validation is only for the comfort of the user, since it can be bypassed easily. Unless you are on very slow connection, you might want to take advantage of XPages server side validators and the error control.

**Update**: use the XSP object to add the event: https://www.notessensei.com/blog/2010/07/meet-the-xsp-object.html

Comment: form event onSubmit in xpages?  confused how that would look in xpages?

Comment: XSP.addPresubmitListener